# runtime of A.concat(A.splice(0,p))

Tags: javascript, runtime

what is the runtime / space of A.concat(A.splice(0,p))? I'm not sure how these are implemented exactly, but to me it would make sense that it is O(n * p) perhaps?

Comment: At most, it requires iterating over `p` elements twice, which means `O(n)` (not sure if the engine can optimize this further due to removing and appending continuous sections). `O(n * p)` isn't a complexity class

Comment: wouldnt iterating over p elements twice be O(p). Also, O(n * p) is perfectly fine as a complexity. It could depends on p somehow

Comment: Linear iteration is always `n`. Eg. iterating over every element in an array of arrays, outer array length X, the inner array length Y, would be said to have complexity `O(n^2)`

Comment: that doesn't make sense. you runtimes should be in the same context of your variables. If its length X and Y the runtime is O(X * Y). You cant even say O(X^2) or O(Y^2)... you can however say O(max(X,Y)^2). But you should always use as tight as bounds as possible - and variables in the context of your algorithm. I was moreso looking for documents somehwere on JS function runtimes

Comment: That's just how Big O notation works - the only "variable" ever used is `n`, to indicate a generic linear iteration time. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)